# Ordinary homogeneous differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

How to solve this one

$y''=(2xy - \frac{5}{x})y' + 4y^2 - \frac{4y}{x^2}$

I know it's homogeneous. I've made replacement $x = e^t$ and $y = ze^{-2t}$ but I had no result.

Comment: MathOverflow is for mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. See Math.StackExchange to ask general questions in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Maple finds

$$y = \dfrac{a}{x^2} \tanh(b - a \ln(x)) $$